# SQL Server Not Recognizing Leading Spaces in Select Query

Tags: sql-server-2016

I get a TXT file from one of our sources systems each night. It's basically a terminal report with headers, footers, titles, column headers, sub-totals, etc. I'm trying to scrape discrete data elements from the file using SQL Server. The file is being FTP'd to a Windows file share. The source system is AIX and the file's encoding is UTF-8, with an EOL marker of LF. I'm using SSIS to import the raw text report into a single column table with each report row being one record in my table. The column I'm storing the rows in is a `VARCHAR(240)` and I'm using SQL Server 2016.

For the report rows that I want to use, the one thing they have in common is that they all start with two spaces. Here's an example record from a text report I've loaded to SQL:

```
COLUMN_NAME

  AD DEPT      0     0     0   0     0     0    0     0    0   0.0   0      0  0.00  0.00      0      0      0   0.0
```

When I try to select the record using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '  %';
```

No rows are returned in my result set. However, `REPLACE` seems to recognize the the row starts with two spaces.

So this:

```
SELECT REPLACE([COLUMN_NAME],' ','$')
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Returns this:

```
COLUMN_NAME

$$AD$DEPT$$$$$$0$$$$$0$$$$$0$$$0$$$$$0$$$$$0$$$$0$$$$$0$$$$0$$$0.0$$$0$$$$$$0$$0.00$$0.00$$$$$$0$$$$$$0$$$$$$0$$$0.0
```

Can someone help me understand why `REPLACE` sees that there are two leading spaces in the row but the plain `SELECT` does not?

Comment: please include a reproduceable example in the form of [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that you have 2 spaces as the start of the column then you can use the single character wildcards in your `LIKE` expression.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE testString (
      sampleImport varchar(20)
)
GO
INSERT testString
VALUES ('  AD DEPT 0 0 0'), ('BD DEPT 0 0 0')
GO

SELECT *
FROM testString
WHERE sampleImport LIKE '[ ][ ]%'
GO
SELECT *
FROM testString
WHERE sampleImport NOT LIKE '[ ][ ]%'
GO
```

The `[]` is used to signify a single character - the specific character is the one enclosed in the brackets.  So placing a single space within the brackets allows you to match the spaces.

I also noted that your criteria had only a single space before the `%` character. Although I cannot see it documented as such, I suspect that your version is failing as it is not seeing a leading space as a valid character for the wildcard (although by definition it should).  When using `LIKE '  %'`  it works with my test data.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  I do have two spaces before the %, but it's hard to tell in the example.  I tried explicitly using a pair of brackets, with space in-between each, against my data set and it still doesn't recognize the space.  Is it possible there's something I haven't accounted for in loading the raw data?  If so, why does the REPLACE work?

Comment: Might be worth checking the string is the length you expect it to be and no extra control characters for example.  With REPLACE working it would seem like there is perhaps something in between the first 2 spaces and the start of the text.

Comment: Thank you Martin!  There was a CR at the beginning of the row.  That's why my select wasn't working.